# Android Studio Manifest error - saying package does not exist

Tags: android, android-manifest

I refactored my package name and put my `CuteMainActivity`in the package `org.azurespot.cutemain.CuteMainActivity`. Plus rearranged all my other classes. So now I get a red error on the `.CuteMainActivity` part in my Manifest, where the activity should launch.

I also changed the top package name of my Manifest to the new one: `org.azurespot`, and also changed my applicationID in my `build.gradle` file to the new package name `org.azurespot` too. Then I rebuilt, cleaned, and even tried `invalidate and restart` to my project but nothing is getting rid of this red error. I also tried to assign the new package/activity name to launch in my run configurations, and got this error:

```
Launching application: org.azurespot/org.azurespot.cutemain.CuteMainActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "org.azurespot/org.azurespot.cutemain.CuteMainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=org.azurespot/.cutemain.CuteMainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {org.azurespot/org.azurespot.cutemain.CuteMainActivity} does not exist
```

One strange thing, is that my package name has the word `(androidTest)` beside it. Would that make things not work? Usually studio creates a regular package name and a `package_name (androidTest)`, but in the refactoring, I only see this `(androidTest)` one.

[image: project structure screenshot]
I have been researching this problem for a while, but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions? Thank you.

**Manifest.java**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.azurespot" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".CuteMainActivity" //This has a red error
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**LogCat** after changed `Manifest` name to `".cutemain.CuteMainActivity"`

```
1480-1480/org.azurespot E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.azurespot, PID: 1480
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.azurespot/org.azurespot.cutemain.CuteMainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.azurespot.cutemain.CuteMainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.azurespot-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.azurespot-2, /system/lib]]
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.azurespot.cutemain.CuteMainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.azurespot-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.azurespot-2, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: change to `org.azurespot.cutemain.CuteMainActivity`

Comment: Did you try specifying a full path in manifest i.e. `org.azurespot.cutemain.CuteMainActivity`  And if doesn't work, go to **Files** at top left corner of IDE, there will be an option (I don't remember the name but it was something like) `Clear cashes and restart` click it, may it solve.

Comment: Thanks @Apurva. I did change it, plus I did the `invalidate and restart` option but it did not work either. However, I got a new error when I tried to run it, and so I added it above.

Comment: Are you sure you have written your `CuteMainActivity.class` correctly? Have you set layout in `setContentView()`?

Comment: I added a photo of my file structure above, do you guys know why it says `(androidTest)` besides my package name? I wonder if that affects things.

Comment: Yes, I have it set to my `xml`: `@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cute_main);`

Comment: Ugh, now my `R` is red in my `CuteMainActivity`, but this was not how it was before. I tried to `invalidate and restart` but no change.

Comment: In the project view you have a little selector which currently should say Android and have a little arrow pointing down. Click on it and change to project, then take a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks @Zoltan for the suggestion, but I did find the solution (whew!) I looked in my `main` folder in `src` and it was empty, all my java files were in the `androidTest` folder, strangely enough. This must have happened without my knowledge when I refactored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah... the package name with `(androidTest)` was indeed the culprit. All of the above answers should have fixed things, but the final problem was that when I refactored (I have no idea how it happened), all of my new package names got put into my `androidTest` directory in the `src` folder, and nothing was in my `main` of my `src` folder. So when my app went looking for the main activity, it could not be found. The fix to this was to put the whole `java` folder back into the `main` folder (as it was empty for some reason), then restart the app and everything worked again. It was not necessary to delete the `androidTest` folder, and it seems fine that it's empty.

Answer (score 1):

You should change it to one of the followings:

```
android:name="org.azurespot.cutemain.CuteMainActivity"
```

or

```
android:name=".cutemain.CuteMainActivity"
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but it didn't work. I did get a new error though when I tried to run it. I post it above.

Comment: Actually your answer did help some, as I had two problems. So thanks!

Comment: @NoniA. you're welcome, it looks like it has to work but i do not know why you get classnotfoundexception.

Comment: It ended up being the issue I wrote in my answer, having to do with all my java files being in the `androidTest` folder. I never would have guessed! :)